# Firebase Firestore - Get collection documents in Security Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Firebase Cloud Firestore Security Rules Reference, we see that we can get a document using `get()` function:

> `get()` takes a path and returns the *resource* at that path.

Is there any way to check if a value already exist in a document of a collection (like mapping documents to check their values)?

I need to check if there is already a document with the field *token* identical to the value I want to set. I have tried this, but `data` is documented to be to a document, not a collection of documents:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /deviceTokens/{tokenId} {
      allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/deviceTokens).data.token != request.data.token;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you need a collection of documents here, rather than a single document.

Comment: @DougStevenson I need to check if there is already a document with the field token identical to the value I want to set

Comment: Sorry if I have made some mistakes with the language, I am Italian

Comment: Is the `{tokenId}` different from what you set in `data.token`?

Comment: @JRLtechwriting `tokenId` references to current document, I need to check all documents in the collection.

Comment: @alessionossa did you ever get any response in Firestore Security Rules for your question ?

Comment: @laurentngu no, I didn't get any response and I didn’t search for any solution for the last 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the check outside of security rules. To check if a value exists on a document in a collection:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('deviceTokens').where("token", "==", newToken).get()
.then(snapshot => {
  if(snapshot.docs.length > 0){
    console.log("token taken");
  } else {
    console.log("token available")
  }
})
```

Comment: the initial question was for Firestore security rules (server side) via firestore.rules syntax (not via client javascript language)